# Quelle est la différence entre « ainsi », « comme ça » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Les deux expressions sont-elles différentes ou non ?

Je voudrais savoir si « ainsi » et « comme ça » ont des sens différents et comment bien les utiliser.

Par exemple:

> 1. Peux-tu le laisser ainsi ?
> 2. Peux-tu le laisser comme ça ?

Answer (score 1):

*Ainsi* et *comme ça* peuvent tout deux signifier *de cette façon, dans cet état*.

Quand c'est le cas, la plus grande différence est celle de registre. *Ainsi* est plus littéraire et formel alors que *comme ça* est du français courant.

Les deux phrases proposées utilisent l'inversion interrogative qui tend à ne plus être utilisée en français parlé avec lequel on entendra plutôt :

> Est-ce que tu peux le laisser comme ça ?

ou simplement une question signalée par l'intonation :

> Tu peux le laisser comme ça ?

*Ainsi* peut aussi être utilisé dans des locutions telles que :

- Ainsi que
- Ainsi de suite
- Pour ainsi dire

On peut aussi noter que les phrases proposées sont ambiguës, on ne sait pas à priori si on fait référence à la façon de laisser (manière) ou ce qui est laissé (résultat).

Comment: merci à toi. Au fait, “ainsi que” est comme “as well as” en anglais?

Comment: Oui, *as well as* correspond bien à *ainsi que*, *de même que*.